# Subview added to image view is out of place

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, subview

I am trying to add a subview (blurview) to an image view, but it is placing it on the bottom right.

Here is the code I used to make the blurview (`viewDidLoad`):

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
self.blurView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
self.blurView.frame = self.view.frame;
```

This is the code I use to add the subview to the image view (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`):

```
FriendsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FriendsTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell.chosenImage addSubview:self.blurView];
```

This is what it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hddej.png

This is what it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Isf.jpg

Comment: Hard to know what's wrong as you have some oddities in your code. As an example, don't `dequeue` a cell in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Use `FriendsTableViewCell *cell = (FriendsTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` instead. Also, you are setting the frame of your blur view in `viewDidLoad` before the cell exists but then attempting to add view to the cell. You need to set the bounds based on the cell's `contentView`. But better yet would be to use constraints between the cell's `contentView` and `blurView`. I suspect you have other problems as well.

Comment: That's what was wrong. I changed that line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `self.view.frame` instead of `self.view.bounds`, so the blur view has taken the coordinates of the UITableViewCell within its parent (the UITableView). Assuming you just want them to be the same size, use the UITableViewCell's bounds

See the section "View Geometry and Coordinate Systems" here for a more detailed explanation of the coordinate systems: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

Comment: I changed that, but it still produces the same effect. When I change it to `self.blurView.bounds = self.view.bounds`, it disappears entirely.